# How to contact yoginis?

Tags: vedas

It is stated that there are 64 yoginis. Where do they reside and how to contact them.? Why are yoginis not visible to me. Do they have bodies or is it an illusion

Comment: There are Yogini sadhanas. Success in them will only yield their vision. We can not ordinarily see any deities either. Same is the case with other supernatural beings.

Comment: Thx for posting this question, good stuff ! :)

Comment: Maybe there could be “yogini” and “dakini” tags, someone could make perhaps, for the HSE questions re these (awesome) entities.

Answer (score 1):

**Where do they reside?**

Yoginis dwell in the different quarters of the heaven.

> The God said: Now I shall describe to you, in the following eight
> couplets, **the Yoginis who dwell in the different quarters of the
> heaven.** I shall start with the East and finish with the north-east
> quarter of the firmament. There names are as follows: The Yoginis
> named **Aksobhya**, **Ruksakarni**, **Raksasi**, **Krpana** and **Aksaya** inhabit the
> eastern quarters of the sky. The Yoginis known as **Pingaksi**, **Aksaya**,
> **Ksema**, **Ila**, **Nilalaya**, **Lila**, **Rakta**, **Balakesi**, **Lalasa** and **Vimala** dwell
> in the southeastern quarter of the firmament. The Yoginis who are named
> **Hutasa**, **Visalaksi**, **Hrinkara**, **Badavamukhi**, **Mahakrura**, **Krodhana**,
> **Bhayankari** and **Mahanana**, reside in the south. .............

**Agni Purana, Part 1, Chapter 52**

**How to contact them?**

You have to worship and propitiate them.

> These Yoginis should be represented as having eight or four hands as
> the case may be and wielding arms according to their own choice and
> who impart all success to their votaries, **on being duly worshipped and
> propitiated.** .....

**Agni Purana, Part 1, Chapter 52**

**Why are yoginis not visible to me. Do they have bodies or is it an illusion?**

You have to worship them in order to see them. Agni Purana says that they exist.

Comment: Thx for posting this ! :) @pradipgangopadhyay

Comment: Please let me know the method of worshipping yoginis

Comment: You need to contact a Tantrik to know the method of worshipping Yoginis.